# Google Compute Engine - How to update code to all instances of an instance group?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I am following [this instruction](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/run-on-compute-engine#multiple_instances) to setup multiple instances or a server cluster on GCE. It worked well, however I don't know how to update the application code. For example, I have some bug fixing and need to update the code and reload all instances. Is there anyway I could do that?

Answer (score 3):

Basically you need to:

1. Create a new template with the bug fix (same way you did it previously).
2. Set it on the instance group manager: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instance-groups/managed/set-instance-template
3. Recreate your instances, use: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instance-groups/managed/recreate-instances

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's a great suggestion indeed. It will provide us full control in the deployment process. However, I find it not very handy if we do it in that way. I've just found this article to [automate deployment process with Chef, Puppet](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/google-compute-engine-management-puppet-chef-salt-ansible), I think it can help us automate a lot of work.

Answer (score 2):

You should use Managed Instance Group Updater: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/updating-managed-instance-groups.

It allows you to recreate all instances within a group from a new template with controlled rate/speed.

Example on how to start a basic update: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/updating-managed-instance-groups#starting_a_basic_rolling_update.